# Fails on returning empty array for [0,0] sum

Tags: python, arrays

Im trying to test function with that tests, btw its always fails with:

> ```
> [0, 0] should equal []
> ```

***Can someone tell please where is my mistake ?***

Tests:

```
Test.describe("Basic tests")

Test.assert_equals(count_positives_sum_negatives([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
8, 9, 10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15]),[10,-65])

Test.assert_equals(count_positives_sum_negatives([0, 2, 3, 0, 5, 6, 7,
8, 9, 10, -11, -12, -13, -14]),[8,-50])

Test.assert_equals(count_positives_sum_negatives([1]),[1,0])

Test.assert_equals(count_positives_sum_negatives([-1]),[0,-1])

Test.assert_equals(count_positives_sum_negatives([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]),[0,0])

Test.assert_equals(count_positives_sum_negatives([]),[])
```

My code:

```
def count_positives_sum_negatives(arr):
    positive_count = 0
    negative_sum = 0
    for n in arr:
        if n > 0:
            positive_count += 1
        elif n < 0:
            negative_sum += n

    return [positive_count, negative_sum]
```

Comment: Reread the requirements for your task. Most likely, there's a specific special case you didn't implement.

Comment: It's hard to tell what is the error, when you failed to include the assignment specifications.  However, I think I figured it out from context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you haven't handled the degenerate case, where there is nothing report because of an empty input list.  Add a line to the top of your function:

```
if len(arr) == 0
    return []
```

Comment: `[0, 0]` is an expected output in one of the test cases.

Comment: @user2357112: so it is; I fixed the solution; thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following procedure needs to applied if a test fails:

1. Narrow down the tests to the one that is failing
2. Look at the input and expected output of that test
3. Change the code so that it matches the desired ouput
4. Check the impact on other tests by running all tests again